# Google cloud print API integration in my application

Tags: android, google-api, google-cloud-print, android-print-framework

I am trying to integrate Google cloud print in Android Application. I do not want to do it through Print framework as my requirement is to directly print from application without any selection process.

For this, I have integrate Google authentication and generate access token for that. I am trying to load printer list using access_token but getting error all the time.

Following are my API call details:

> URL : https://www.google.com/cloudprint/search
>
> Type : POST
>
> Header :
>
> Authorization : OAuth ACCESS_TOKEN
>
> Content-Type : application/json

Error message is:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>User credentials required</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
        <H1>User credentials required</H1>
        <H2>Error 403</H2>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Authorization header bearer token?

Comment: @DalmTo already tried.

Comment: Please include a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @DaImTo I got the issue. Scope was mission while authentication. That's generating issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a google group. Add members by direct invite:

1. Your gmail account (gmail email address)
2. Your google service account from which access token was furnished (service account email address)

Then follow the below steps:

1. Go to google.com/cloudprint
2. Select your printer and click Share tab. Add following members under invite people:

   - google service account email address
   - google group email address ( eg, xyz@googlegroups.com)

Then try calling GCP APIs. It will work perfectly.